# Missing AdaptiveImageComponentServlet.java in AEM 6

Tags: aem

I am following a tutorial from below URL how to create adaptive image component

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/mobile/responsive.html#Using%20Adaptive%20Images

I have checked my author and publisher instance however I cannot find the file /apps/geometrixx-commons/src/core/src/main/java/info/geometrixx/commons/impl/servlets/AdaptiveImageComponentServlet.java

Any idea where I can get the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check in the below path:

/libs/foundation/src/impl/src/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/impl/AdaptiveImageComponentServlet.java

Source: http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__hbcy-hi_all_i_amfoll.html